# Url rewriting using .htaccess gives 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**here is my htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.in$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.mysite\.in\/" [R=301,L]


RewriteRule \.(css|jpeg|gif|png|js|ico|img|chat)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^detail/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]

#RewriteRule ^$ index.php?name=kal

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?name=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?name=$1&place=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?name=$1&place=$2
```

When I request **https://www.mysite.in/myname/myplace** It works fine

But when I request **https://www.mysite.in/myname-n-m/myplace** it gives 404 Error not found

Basically my first parameter will have - (hyphens in it) , Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite rule contains: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`, which says: letters + numbers. So change it to: `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+` to also include hyphens

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this...

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?name=$1&place=$2
```